# How to use Sphinx BuildExcerpts

Tags: python, full-text-search, sphinx

So, I've set up a Sphinx configuration file. I have a very simple schema with two fields, title and body, where the title is the name of a novel and body is the complete novel itself. To keep things simple, I've only added one novel. The indexer worked just fine and the Python API made querying sphinxd a breeze. I'm really impressed so far, this seems the easiest to set up full-text search engine I've investigated so far (much easier than Lucene or Solr and faster than Woosh).

I have skipped any DB backend. I have my novels in plain .txt format, and I've added the
sample one with this simple xml (through xmlpipe)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sphinx:docset>
       <sphinx:document id="1">
             <title><![CDATA[Dan Simmons - I Canti di Hyperion 3 - Endymion]]></title>
             <body><![CDATA[ * ALL THE NOVEL HERE * ]]></body>
       </sphinx:document>
</sphinx:docset>
```

By the way, I search the archive for "tartaruga", it is italian for "turtle" and I'm sure that the word is the file. In fact, is found three times, and I guess that's what Sphinx returns to me (`'hits': 3`). This is the complete result:

```
{'attrs': [],
'error': '',
'fields': ['title', 'body'],
'matches': [{'attrs': {}, 'id': 1, 'weight': 1}],
'status': 0,
'time': '0.392',
'total': 1,
'total_found': 1,
'warning': '',
'words': [{'docs': 1, 'hits': 3, 'word': 'tartaruga'}]}
```

What I want to have, in the end, is something like this:

```
[
  {
    'title': 'Dan Simmons - I Canti di Hyperion 3 - Endymion',
    'body': 'il vecchio mostrò quel suo sorriso a becco di tartaruga. — non bisogna dimenticare il palazzo dello shrike, né il nostro vecchio amico shrike, giusto? non ce ne sono altre?'
  },
  {
    'title': 'Dan Simmons - I Canti di Hyperion 3 - Endymion',
    'body': '— vieni più vicino, raul endymion. — la voce pareva il rumore di una lama spuntata che sfregasse su pergamena. le labbra si muovevano come il becco d\'una tartaruga.'
  },
  {
    'title': 'Dan Simmons - I Canti di Hyperion 3 - Endymion',
    'body': 'il becco di tartaruga ebbe una contrazione, la grossa testa si mosse in un cenno d\'assenso. notai ora che il viso del vecchio, malgrado i danni provocati dai secoli, aveva ancora tratti netti e spigolosi... un\'aria da satiro.'
  },
]
```

I mean, an array of occurrences with the book the excerpt is taken from and the word within a context (i've chosen sentencies, but *n* words before or after the match would work). I think I have to use BuildExcerpts, but how?

Also, if I want to match both *tartaruga* (turtle) and *tartarughe* (turtles), I'd like to issue a query like `tartarug*`. How to do this is Sphinx? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know the PHP API has BuildExceprts to do this, you can find an example here: http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=php_api_docs#buildexcerpts_documents_index_words_options I'm not sure if the python API has the same

Comment: hmmm, does this mean that i have to load in memory 100 novels if i have 100 matches from 100 different books?

Comment: Yes. you need to load the text, then send it to sphinx to build the excerpts.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing for a project I work on. My suggestion would be that loading an entire book as a single field isn't a great idea unless you're only ever going to work with one book, rather than many books. Here's how I do it.

1. Book is stored in MySQL database one page at a time.
2. Run sphinx across database with several million pages of text -
   works very fast, returns every page with the text you are looking for (or depending on the number of pages in the DB, just get the first 30 or whatever).
3. Use Excerpt Builder to get an excerpt from a page, and then highlight the search phase.
4. If Python doesn't have access to the excerpt builder (it may be php only), then you could do the same job without too much difficulty using regular expressions - you just need to find your search phrase and do a regex to find so much text either side, and another regex to add highlighting.

You could write a python script (I use a PHP script run from the bash shell) to extract your text one page at a time, sanitize it, and add it to the database.

You'd need a database with at least two tables something like

`books (fields could be called, id, name, author)`

`pages (fields would be id, book_id, page_text)`

Sphinx would return you a page id, you then get the page from MySQL using a simple query...

`SELECT page_text FROM pages WHERE id = $idreturnedbysphinx;`

You then send that returned text to the text excerpter/text highlighter.

Sphinx can either search for exact words or stemmed words (and much much more), but you need to set this up in your sphinx.conf file.

You need at least two index definitions:

```
indexer indexname1
{
     #source database connection and sql query
      source                = src1
      path                  = /var/data/indexname1
     [... other settings ...]
     #make sure stemming is switched off
     morphology             = none


}
#child index inherits the above, and add stemming
index indexname1stemmed : indexname1
{
    path            = /var/data/indexname1stemmed
    morphology      = stem_en
    index_exact_words   = 1
}
```

You then also need to specify in your sphinx search the match mode you want to use. I don't know the python syntax, but the sphinx manual sets it out better than I can:
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#matching-modes

You could do all this without a SQL database and keep it in text files, but I'd probably go to one text file per page as a more manageable way to work, otherwise you'll be back to returning the entire ebook as your search result.